# pl/sql query to remove duplicates and replace the data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
data_id  new_data_id  first_name    last_name

  1                        john        smith
  2                        john        smith
  3                        john        smith
  4                        jeff        louis
  5                        jeff        louis
  6                        jeff        louis
```

The above table has duplicate first and last names, and the data_id is different for all of them. In order to remove these duplicates, I would need to write a SQL query to replace the highest data_id in new_data_id column. My output would look something like this:

```
data_id  new_data_id  first_name    last_name

  1           3            john        smith
  2           3            john        smith
  3           3            john        smith
  4           6            jeff        louis
  5           6            jeff        louis
  6           6            jeff        louis
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Are you actually trying to delete the duplicated records, or are you just trying to tag them all with the maximum ID?  Please post your specific RDBMS version.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an Oracle **analytic function**.

The aggregate function `MAX` can be used to select the highest data_id from your entire resultset, but that's not exactly what you need. Instead, use its alter ego, the `MAX` analytic function like so:

```
SELECT
  data_id,
  MAX(data_id) OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name) AS new_data_id,
  first_name,
  last_name
FROM employees
ORDER BY data_id
```

This works by "partitioning" your resultset by first_name and last_name, and then it performs the given function within that subset.

Good luck!

Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48b29/4

More info can be found here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Answer (score 0):

If you need a change *in place*, a correlated update is probably the simplest way to write that:

```
UPDATE T
SET "new_data_id" =
     (SELECT MAX("data_id") FROM T T2 
        WHERE T2."first_name" = T."first_name" 
          AND T2."last_name" = T."last_name")
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/51a69/1